# Telerik control shifts down asp panel when setting display false

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, internet-explorer, telerik

I have 4 panels I want to show or hide depending on a certain selection in a radcombobox.
Until now I was using the code behind and doing this through postback without any problems. 
When I attached the panels to the telerik ajax settings so as not have a postback each time there were problems with IE. 
The panels hide as they are supposed to but in IE they shift down, the hidden divs still take vertical space.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code and screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by putting the radtabstrip and radpageview in an ajaxcontrol as well. Previously they weren't. It seems this solved the problem.